# Bubble parent not working in android appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator

I have a view like so

```
function addButton(btnName, btnTitle, dataDisplay) {
     var buttonView = Ti.UI.Button({
        id: "btn_view_" + btnName,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        bubbleParent: false
    });



    var chevronLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "chevron_lbl_" + btnName,
        //color: Alloy.Globals.colors.gray,
        //backgroundColor: "blue",
        font: {
            fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
            fontSize: 20
        },
        height: Ti.UI.FILL,
        right: 5,
        text: Alloy.Globals.fa.chevronRight,
        textAlign: 'center',
        width: 32,

        touchEnabled: false
    });
    //chevronLabel.addEventListener("click", displayList);
    if (Alloy.isTablet) {
        chevronLabel.font = {
            fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
            fontSize: 25
        };
    }
    select_button = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        id: "btn_" + btnName,
        hintText: btnTitle,
        dataToDisplay: dataDisplay,
        //backgroundColor: "yellow"
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 6,
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: '90%',
        editable: false,
        value: "",
        left: "2%",
        bubbleParent: false

    });
    select_button.addEventListener("click", displayList);
    buttonView.add(select_button);
    buttonView.add(chevronLabel);
    return buttonView;
}
```

I am adding it to a view in the UI. My select_button has an event listener. I set the bubble parent to false but I am having to double click to make it work. i just want to click once to go to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `singletap` event for text-fields if their `editable` property is set to `false`. Click event works when text-fields are able to gain focus on their own. But by setting `editable` to `false`, text-fields failed to gain focus in first attempt.

Also, this is not a good pattern to create non-editable fields as text-fields always try to gain focus on Android and it might lead to unexpected outcomes.